# UIImage pointer is null

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage

So I have this line of code

```
self.rateView.notSelectedStar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"kermit_empty.png"];
```

and in the setter I do this

```
    NSLog(@"Pointer is %@",initialNotSelectedStar);
```

This prints a null pointer. The images are inside the xcode project, and nothing shows when I build and run.

Is this because I haven't alloced, or because my file path is wrong, or because of something else?

Comment: are you sure your image file is in your bundle?

Comment: so I tried two things - I put it right in the project, and then tried putting it under the App folder inside the project

Comment: have you added the file to the target?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means

Comment: Try this: self.rateView.notSelectedStar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"kermit_empty.png"];

Comment: compiler yells at me when I do that- image isn't a property of UIImage

Comment: can you find the image name in the "Build Phases"-->"Copy Bundle Resources"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the image file to your bundle first. You can check whether the file name is in the "Build Phases"==>"Copy Bundle Resources" list, if not, drag and drop your file to there.

Comment: where is this Build Phases list?

Comment: in the project settings page, there is "General" "Capabilities"...tabs

Comment: in the project settings page, you should select the target first

Comment: wait so the project settings page only has Buld and Snapshots as tabs

Comment: select the target at the first beginning tab not the project, you will see more tabs.

Comment: ah...so these images are in the Copy Bundle Resources list

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41915/discussion-between-chancy-and-praks5432)